# API for audio fingerprinting for speech ioS

Tags: ios, audio, speech, fingerprint, phoneme

Any suggestions/pointers on finding an API for audio fingerprinting for iOS for using with syllables and single phonemes.

Comment: Audio fingerprinting is not usually the technique used for identifying syllables and phonemes.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn - can you suggest a technique that might be useful?

Comment: I suggest you start your search with wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Algorithms